# How to apply a LUT filter with FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to apply a LUT-filter on a video,so i decide to use FFMPEG,but i don't know how to apply this LUT image on the video ,

This is the LUT image:
[image]

Can anyone tell me how to do this With FFMPEG ?

Thanks.

Comment: Questions like this belong on VideoProduction

Answer (score 2):

You can use [haldclut](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#haldclut-1) filter.

```
ffplay input -vf "movie=uUyIr.png, [in] haldclut"
```

Comment: I did this just like your answer,but the video is green,can you tell me more about this? thanks

Comment: I am not a programmer, and not good at english. I am using zeranoe ffmpeg.
Video color is depend on image used by haldclut filter.
Another image used by haldclut is here http://www.quelsolaar.com/technology/clut.html

If you want to output video, change format yuv420p, default is rgb24.

ffmpeg -i http://download.blender.org/peach/bigbuckbunny_movies/big_buck_bunny_480p_surround-fix.avi -vf "movie=uUyIr.png, [in] haldclut,format=yuv420p" output

Answer (score 0):

This is OBS Studio compatible LUT file. It is different from the format that is supported by the FFmpeg *lut3d* filters.

Because it is different you need to apply similar color adjustments to the FFmpeg supported LUT and use it instead. The closes FFmpeg's alternative is `haldclut` filter (storage is different). To generate 8-bit FFmpeg compatible neutral Hald LUT use next command:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i haldclutsrc=8 -frames:v 1 neutral_hald_clut_ffmpeg.png
```

Now you can add it to the OBS Studio as Image Source, set Base and Canvas to match the image size (512x512) and add Apply LUT filter (specify your LUT filepath). Since v26.x.x of the OBS Studio you can take Screenshot (Source) that will be saved in PNG format (don't forget to use RGB, Full Range in the Advanced Settings of the application to not get hit by chroma planes conversions if you are try to save it in other way).

The new modified hald clut can be used in FFmpeg like:

```
ffmpeg -i "source.mp4" -i "modified_hald_clut_ffmpeg.png" -filter_complex "haldclut" "result.mp4"
```

or (uses filter graph, OS paths escaped, Windows)

```
ffmpeg -i "C:\temp\source.mp4" -vf "movie=C\\:\\\\temp\\\\modified_hald_clut_ffmpeg.png [clut];[in][clut] haldclut" -c:v libx264 -crf 23 "C:\temp\result.mp4"
```

Maybe you will need to apply some additional FFmpeg filters too (to set output color space, range, matrix etc.)